# Convergence and proving inequality, Real Analysis

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $a_n$ converges to $a$ and that $a_n \ge b$ for each $n$. Prove that $a \ge b$

Please help me prove this in general.

In class we have been doing specific examples where we are given $\varepsilon > 0$ and we find $N(\varepsilon)$ such that $|a_n-a|\le\varepsilon$ for all $n \ge N$.

I finally caught on to doing this with a specific sequence. Please help me in the right direction as to proving without any numbers to work with

Comment: Writing something like |$a_n$-$a$| when MathJax is available is weird.  I changed it to $|a_n-a|\le\varepsilon$.  That way the minus sign looks like a minus sign rather than like a hyphen, and there is proper spacing.  I also made various other similar changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the $\varepsilon$ characterization:

Fix *any* $\varepsilon>0$; there exists $n_0\geq 0$ such that for all $n\geq n_0$, $\lvert a_n - a\rvert \leq \varepsilon$.
In particular, $a \geq a_n-\varepsilon \geq b -\varepsilon$ for all $n\geq n_0$.

But this implies (with no dependence on $n_0$) $a \geq b -\varepsilon$. And this is true for *every* $\varepsilon > 0$. We will use this.

By contradiction, suppose $a < b$. Then, take $\varepsilon\stackrel{\rm{}def}{=}\frac{b-a}{2}>0$. With the discussion above,
$$ a \geq b - \varepsilon = \frac{b}{2} + \frac{a}{2}$$
which implies $\frac{a}{2} \geq \frac{b}{2}$, i.e. $a \geq b$. Contradiction.

Comment: +1, though I would regard the first half as sufficient.

Comment: Did you skip any steps between supposing $a$ < $b$ and then choosing &epsilon; ?

Comment: Why? $\varepsilon$ is just chosen to be smaller than the difference $b-a$, the latter being positive.